# Calculator and calculus package: result [.] dot instead [,] comma

Tags: formatting, calculations

My codes,

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{calculator}
 \usepackage{calculus}

 \newcommand\teo{3}
 \newcommand\job{,5}

 \begin{document}
 \MULTIPLY{\teo}{340}\W
 \MULTIPLY{\job}{5605}\WW
 \ADD{\W}{\WW}\credit
 \credit
 \end{document}
```

And result, **3822.5**

Could it be, **3822,5?**

I didn't find duplicate another question. I found like its, don't working in full my code. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `siunitx` with it's `\num` macro and `output-decimal-marker` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{calculus}
\usepackage{siunitx}     %% or make it global by \usepackage[output-decimal-marker = {,}]{siunitx}

  \newcommand\teo{3}
  \newcommand\job{,5}

\begin{document}
   \MULTIPLY{\teo}{340}\W
   \MULTIPLY{\job}{5605}\WW
   \ADD{\W}{\WW}\credit
   \credit

   \num[output-decimal-marker = {,}]{\credit}

   \ROUND[4]{\credit}{\credit}

   \num[output-decimal-marker = {,}]{\credit}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are lot of options that `\num` macro can take. For details, refer `siunitx` manual.

Comment: Good working, like added picture. But **dot** is lost, 3 **.** 822,500. I don't find in its package about thousand separator. @Harish Kumar

Comment: @Özgür You want dot as thousand separator? Are you sure?

Comment: @Özgür `\num[group-minimum-digits =3, group-separator = {.},output-decimal-marker = {,}]{\credit}`. But *no* warranty!

Comment: /@Harish Kumar/ Yes, I want dot as only thousand separator (no after comma). Your code is result, **#.###,###.#** (indeed no warrant :)). As a matter of fact, you answered according my question, opened this subject. The subject is closed.

Answer (score 6):

This is not related to `calculator` and `calculus` packages.
There are several utilities to print decimal numbers with comma as decimal separator. Try, for example, the `numprint` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{calculus}
\usepackage{numprint}

  \newcommand\teo{3}
  \newcommand\job{,5}

\begin{document}
   \MULTIPLY{\teo}{340}\W
   \MULTIPLY{\job}{5605}\WW
   \ADD{\W}{\WW}\credit
   \numprint{\credit}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am trying, @Robert Fuster.

Comment: Add **\ROUND[4]{\credit}{\credit} **\ADD{\W}{\WW}\credit** between **\numprint{\credit}** result **3.822,500.0** . I'm not making to **3.822,5000** .

Comment: It's good that I learnt calculator and calculus packages, @Robert Fuster.